# How to get the nearest number which is divisible by the divisor in scala

Tags: scala

How to get the nearest number which is divisible by the divisor in scala.

For example

```
-if divisor -20 and dividend is 15, the number 15 has to be converted to 20
-if divisor -20 and dividend is 39, the number 39 has to be converted to 40 
-if divisor -20 and dividend is 45, the number 45 has to be converted to 60 
-if divisor -20 and dividend is 60, the number  conversion is not required.
```

I have tried this. But it is not working for negative numbers.

```
def makeNum(num:Double,buc:Int){
if (num % buc == 0) println(num) else
println(  buc * (num/buc).ceil )
}
   makeNum(39,20) --> 40.0 - working
   makeNum(-10,20) --> -0.0 - Not correct
```

Comment: And what have you tried? do you have an algorithm in mind? are you able to solve the problem by hand without using a computer? do you know any other programming language or Scala is your first one? what can you use, what can't you use? - this looks like a [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), please read the provided link and the basic faq like **how to ask** and **mcve**.

Comment: I have to use scala here.

Comment: I am trying now,,but it seems stuck .

Comment: var num = 39d
val buc = 20

if (num % buc == 0) println(num) else
println(  buc * (num/buc).ceil )   I am trying this .But got confused if this works everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you, but you have to understand that this is not a free coding service. We are to help not to work for free. All the questions I made are for you to show us that you genuinely tried to solve the problem. First, instead of comments, please edit the question proving details, for example, do you have a pseudocode to solve the problem? If so, please add it. Do you know how to solve it in any other programming language, if so, provide that code. Have you tried to solve it in **Scala**, but got stuck, please provide that code and the precise question / problem that you have.

Comment: Yes.Understand and agree with you completly.

Comment: var num = 39d val buc = 20 if (num % buc == 0) println(num) else println( buc * (num/buc).ceil ) I hvae tried this. But didnt get the confidence since I am new to scala.

Comment: Please edit the question and use proper formatting so the code is readable instead of comments _(and delete them afterward)_. Second, as an advice create a function with receive the inputs and return the answer instead of using hardcoded values. Finally, what exactly do you mean with you do not get the confidence? Is the solution mathematically correct, have you tested with many inputs, do you know it from other language but  you are not sure the code is correct?

Comment: Have edited the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't want the "nearest" number, as stated in the title, but actually the "next" number, as in "away from zero." If that's the case then your original design is pretty close. You just need to account for the sign, as in "direction away from zero."

```
def makeNum(num :Double, buc :Int) :Double = {
  val sign = if (num*buc < 0) -1 else 1
  buc*sign * (num/buc*sign).ceil
}

makeNum(39,20)    //res0: Double = 40.0
makeNum(-10,20)   //res1: Double = -20.0
makeNum(45, -20)  //res2: Double = 60.0
makeNum(-7, -3)   //res3: Double = -9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You were too close.  But, the problem wasn't really the negative numbers, but that it always searched for the next number, but the closets one could be a previous number.
Also, your code didn't follow a common best practice of separation of concerns, your function should just return the number not printing it.

Here is the full code.

```
def findClosestDivisible(dividend: Int, divisor: Int): Int =
  if (dividend % divisor == 0) {
    // Return the dividend if it is already divisible.
    dividend
  } else {
    // Find the quotient.
    val quotient = dividend / divisor

    // 1st possible closest number. 
    val n1 = divisor * quotient

    // 2nd possible closest number.
    val n2 =
      if ((dividend * divisor) > 0)
        divisor * (quotient + 1)
      else
        divisor * (quotient - 1)

    // Return the closest number.
    import math.abs
    if (abs(dividend - n1) < abs(dividend - n2)) n1
    else n2
  }
```

***Note**: The code is based on the algorithm on [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-closest-n-divisible-m/), I just limited myself to implement it in **Scala***.